# R Shiny app crashes when fread key parameter doesn't have that specific column name

Tags: r, shiny, fread, shinydashboard

How to pass the "key" parameter from data.table::fread function without shiny crashes when uploaded dataset that doesn't have that specific column name? In other words, if I upload a dataset that doesn't have the "key" column it can't crash and also it should has no output or just a warning message.

Here I have two dataset. The first one, [test1.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cm61i1427qbxn4j/test1.csv?dl=0), has the key column and the second one, [test2.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfil43cyjtzt5cl/test2.csv?dl=0), doesn't have it.

My code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ';'),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   ''),
      tags$hr(),
      p('If you want a sample .csv or .tsv file to upload,',
        'you can first download the sample',
        a(href = 'mtcars.csv', 'mtcars.csv'), 'or',
        a(href = 'pressure.tsv', 'pressure.tsv'),
        'files, and then try uploading them.'
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('contents')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  arq <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    req(input$file1)
    arq$data <- data.table::fread(input$file1$datapath,
                                         header = input$header,
                                         sep = input$sep,
                                         quote = input$quote,
                                         key="SPECIAL")
  })

  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    output$contents = DT::renderDataTable(arq$data)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The `key` argument in `fread` is optional so you can just not use it.

Comment: Hey Gregor, first, thank you for answering. I know it is optional, but I want to use this argument in order to avoid people uploading wrong files.

Comment: Ah, seems like I mised that part. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the `key` argument when reading the data and set the key afterwards with `data.table::setkey`.

```
observeEvent(input$file1,{
  req(input$file1)
  dat <- data.table::fread(input$file1$datapath, header = input$header,
                           sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)
  if ("SPECIAL" %in% names(data)){
    data.table::setkey(dat, "SPECIAL")
    arq$data <- dat
  } else {
    showModal(modalDialog("Column 'SPEACIAL' is missing"))
    arq$data <- NULL
  }
})
```

Comment: That's it! I was not aware of this function `setkey`. Thanks! I just needed to change `setkey` to  `data.table::setkey` to get this working. Thanks for helping me, Gregor!

Comment: You are very welcome. If I adressed all your issues, please accept the answer so other people will see this question marked as "solved".